# default select option in jsp/html using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

```
<select name="clientName" id="clientName"> 
<%for(int index = 0; index <= clientList.size()-1 ;index++){ %>
<option value="<%=( (ClientNames)clientList.get(index) ).getId() %>"><%=( (ClientNames)clientList.get(index) ).getClientNames() %></option><%} %>
```

My problem in the option list i have to show clientName as "select" as default .In DB i have added a clientName as "select" how i can compare that here and put "select" as default or is there any solution in which i don't have to add "select" in the DB.
Or is there any javascript code which i can put so that default value will be "select" of that option.

Comment: Please share sample html and data.

Comment: If you have to select a default value every time, then rather than adding it in the database, simply add an extra option with attribute selected.

Answer (score 1):

Just write out a first option, then use php for the rest:

```
<select name="clientName" id="clientName"> 
<option name="" value="">Client Name</option>
<%for(int index = 0; index <= clientList.size()-1 ;index++){ %>
<option value="<%=( (ClientNames)clientList.get(index) ).getId() %>"><%=( (ClientNames)clientList.get(index) ).getClientNames() %></option><%} %>
```

for an added effect, use jQuery to remove that option from the actual list:

```js
$('option[value=""]').hide()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="clientName" id="clientName"> 
    <option name="" value="">Client Name</option>
    <option name="Jennifer Black" value="0">Jennifer Black</option>
    <option name="Henry Johnson" value="1">Henry Johnson</option>
    <option name="Jack Hunnington" value="2">Jack Hunnington</option>
    <option name="Mary Green" value="3">Mary Green</option>
</select>
```